# How to use badge component from material design 3 in flutter 3.3.7

Tags: flutter

I recently find that flutter supports material design 3 by enabling the useMaterial3 in ThemeData. However, when I try to use the Badge component from material design 3, it could not be found, and I also cannot find too much information about the newly introduced components in material design 3. Can I please get some guidance on it? Is there any list of components from material design 3 can be used? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As of now, the Material Design 3 widgets aren't well documented, so I usually look up the associated GitHub pull request and read it.

In the [Bring Material 3 to Flutter #91605](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/91605) issue's description under the "Components" section, you can find a list of pull requests for all implemented Material Design 3 widgets.

For example, here is the pull request that [adds support for the Material Badge widget](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/114560). In the description, you can find examples of how to use the Badge widget:

> Badges are typically added above an Icon widget that's part of a
> button or navigation item. For example:
>
> ```
> BottomNavigationBarItem(
>  icon: Badge(
>    label: Text('1'),
>    child: Icon(Icons.business),
>  ),
>  label: 'Business',   
> ),
> ```
>
> A "small" badge, displayed as tiny filled circle, doesn't specify a
> label:
>
> ```
> BottomNavigationBarItem(
>  icon: Badge(
>    child: Icon(Icons.home),
>  ),
>  label: 'Home',
> ),
> ```

Comment: This answer was also helpful in showing where the Badge should ideally be placed, I think. For my `IconButton`, I was wondering if the `Badge` should be a parent to the whole widget or be in the `icon` argument. It seems to match Material 3 design guidelines in the latter case, as is shown here.

Answer (score 0):

You can start using Material 3 [`Badge`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Badge-class.html) widget in Flutter 3.7.

Ref: https://medium.com/flutter/whats-new-in-flutter-3-7-38cbea71133c